# Не печатается документ из консольного приложения, если его запустить через xp_cmdshell в SQL среде

Tags: c#, sql-server

Документ печатается без проблем при ручном запуске, у того же пользователя, который был закреплён на SQL Server через команду **EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account user, pass**. 
Код приложения, который вызывает печать:

```
 public static bool PrintPdFs2(string pdfFileName,         System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printersettings)
{
    try
    {
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = pdfFileName,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                Verb = "PrintTo",
                Arguments = "\"" + printersettings.PrinterName + "\"",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit(8000);
        p.Kill();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Я проверял входящие параметры, они верные, указан правильный путь до файла и приходит тот принтер, который нужен. Также я вижу, что в процессе вызова данной команды на стороне сервера запускается Adobe Reader DC, значит что процесс всё таки запускается. Проверял файл, который он печатает, он не пустой. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что ещё можно сделать?

**UPDATE**

Расскажу о том как решил проблему, мало ли кому-то это пригодится и съэкономит время, т.к. я лично на это дело убил почти 8 часов.
Когда вы вписываете юзера в **sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account** вы указываете с какими правами запускать приложение, запускается же оно от имени пользователя указанного в конфигурации самого sql server.

Я пошёл по не правильному пути решив, что проблема в том что у пользователя от которого запускается приложение нет прав или ещё что-то там, т.к. посмотреть что происходит на его стороне было не возможно (как сказали мне админщики, у него нет своего рабочего пространства), то у меня появилась задача попробовать запустить данное приложение от имени другого пользователя. Задача не тривиальная, но я нашёл способ как это можно сделать, это использовать приложение psexec, правда запускать оно может только приложение распаложенное на другом сервере. Каково было моё разочерование, когда я после нескольких часов смог запустить приложение из под того пользователя, который мне нужен и печать так и не пошла...

В общем после играния с бубном с запуском приложения из под другого пользователя, я решил найти альтернативы стандартной печати с помощью стороних продуктов, у которых есть возможность печатать pdf файлы. И нашёл, это pdfium, только ставьте не последнюю версию, иначе придётся ставить доп.модуль (я поставил 2.10.0), плюс там есть доп.настройки этого модуля, почитайте.

**В общем вопрос по поводу того почему не печатается документ стандартным методом открыт, но если нужен обходной метод воспользуйтесь pdfium.**

Comment: Файл на сервере лежит или на сетевом ресурсе?

Comment: Да, файл лежит, рядом с исполняемым файлом на сервере. Сейчас выяснилось, что Adobe Reader DC запускается из под другого пользователя, какой-то sql_start, не пойму откуда он взялся, может быть в нём проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего в нем, видимо ему не хватает прав